# xmdp:http-get and xdmp:insert-document

Tags: marklogic

I am trying to get XML feed from twitter using marklogic XDMP API, I am able to get XML in Xquery console, but not able to figure out how to transform that xml and put into named database. I am doing following:

1. When hit this url "http://search.twitter.com/search.atom?q=pankaj&since_id=1212121" using `xdmp:http-get` function I get following XML:

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
     <twitter>
       <entry>
         <id>1212121</id>
         <content>did u hear what he talked about Pankaj</content>
       </entry>
       <entry>
        <id>1212122</id>
         <content>abc xyz abc xyz</content>
       </entry>
    </twitter>
   ```
2. Now I want to split this xml into per `<entry>` document and insert into marklogic database.
3. Also this script should be scheduled for every 30 second, next hit should append last entry's id in `since_id` field in URL.

I am trying following but getting some error, also I don't know where to give DB name and how to append `since_id`.

```
let $content := xdmp:http-get("http://search.twitter.com/search.atom?q=pankaj&since_id=191622916163641344",
 <options xmlns="xdmp:document-get">
   <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
 </options>)
return  
for $i in $content//entry
return
xdmp:document-insert(
     "/example.xml", $content//entry,
     xdmp:default-permissions(), 
     xdmp:default-collections(), 
 10)
```

Answer (score 3):

One error was probably a complaint about the un-escaped ampersand, which, in XQuery (like XML) needs to be escaped using `&amp;`.

You also need to declare the Atom namespace, since the content returned from Twitter uses that as its default namespace.

You'll also want to give each document a unique name; otherwise, MarkLogic will throw a CONFLICTINGUPDATES error. In the solution below, I use the tweet ID in the resulting document's URI (parsing it from the `<atom:id>` element).

To update the since_id value, you have several options. Unfortunately, the XML from Twitter doesn't include the pristine tweet ID as its own value of an element or attribute, which means we won't be able to create a range index on it without first modifying the document upon insert (to include such a field). But we can take advantage of the fact that we're using the tweet ID in the URI. Enabling the URI lexicon (global database option in the admin UI) would then allow you to call `cts:uris()` to easily get the latest tweet ID that you've stored.

Here's the full solution I came up with using this technique:

```
declare namespace atom="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom";
declare variable $initial-tweet-id := "191622916163641344";
declare variable $uri-prefix := "/tweets/";
declare variable $uri-suffix := ".xml";
declare variable $latest-tweet-uri := cts:uri-match(concat($uri-prefix,"*"))[last()];
declare variable $latest-tweet-id := if ($latest-tweet-uri)
                                     then substring-after(
                                            substring-before($latest-tweet-uri,$uri-suffix),
                                            $uri-prefix)
                                     else $initial-tweet-id;


let $content := xdmp:http-get(
                  concat("http://search.twitter.com/search.atom?q=pankaj&amp;since_id=",
                         $latest-tweet-id),
 <options xmlns="xdmp:document-get">
   <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
 </options>)
for $entry in $content//atom:entry
let $tweet-id := tokenize($entry/atom:id, ":")[last()]
return
  ( xdmp:log(concat("Adding tweet:", $tweet-id)),
    xdmp:document-insert(
     concat($uri-prefix, $tweet-id, $uri-suffix),
     $entry,
     xdmp:default-permissions(), 
     xdmp:default-collections(), 
     10)
  )
```

To run this every 30 seconds, you can use the admin UI to set up a scheduled task (Configure -> Groups -> Default -> Scheduled Tasks). That's also where you'd specify what database to run this on. (In Query Console, you just use the "Content Source" drop-down menu.)

Alternative approaches:

- Insert an element on load which stores the tweet ID and then use a range index on that to look up the highest value.
- Create a dateTime range index on `<atom:published>`, use that to find the latest tweet, and extract the tweet ID from the `<atom:id>` value.

My solution and the first of the two above alternatives don't require any disk reads, so they're preferable in that regard.

Comment: Thank you for your help. This script is working perfectly for me.

Answer (score 0):

See the reference manual page for xdmp:http-get.  xdmp:http-get returns a sequence of items.

From the reference manual:

> The first node in the output of xdmp:http-get is the response header
>   from the http server.
>
> The second node in the output of xdmp:http-get is the response from
>   the http server. The response is treated as text, XML, or binary,
>   depending on the content-type header sent from the http server. If the
>   node is html, the header should indicate text/html, which is returned
>   as a text document by default. The type of document is determined by
>   the mimetypes mappings, and you can change the mappings in the Admin
>   Interface as needed. If you happen to know that the response is XML,
>   even if the header does not specify it as XML, and want to process the
>   response as XML, you can wrap the response in an xdmp:unquote call to
>   parse the response as XML. You could also use the xml
>   option (in the xdmp:document-get namespace) to tell the API to treat
>   the document as XML. Also, if you know the response is an HTML
>   document, you can wrap the response in an xdmp:tidy call, which will
>   treat the text as HTML, clean it up, and return an XHTML XML document.

You should check the response type and status from the first item.  if it's a text/xml response, then you can do

```
for $i in $content[2]//entry
```

To get something to run every 30 seconds, you can use a scheduled task.  And if you want to only store new docs, you could store each one via the unique twitter URL/ID that twitter provides for each tweet.  You can also store the last 'id' in the database in a document and then pluck it out and update it each time you run your fetcher.